# I cannot display a modified data from csv file

Tags: csv, d3.js, setinterval

I am a newbie in d3.js.
I'm trying to display new data from csv file.. but I can't. A following is my test javascript file and inv.csv.

When I change the content of inv.csv using text editor, I can see the changed value from the output of console.log(), but I can't display it to web browswer through d3.js.

Additionally, I have one more question. I want to make a dynamic web page from real time data. To do that, I'll update a data file periodically and show it to web page via d3.js.
Is this a good or reasonable design concept? What is your recommendation?

Thank you

[test.js]

```
function redraw() {
d3.text("inv.csv", function(datasetText) {

    var parsedCSV = d3.csv.parseRows(datasetText);
    console.log(parsedCSV[1][2]);

    d3.select("#viz")
        .selectAll("h3")
        .data(parsedCSV[1])
      .enter().append("h3")
        .text(function(d){return d;});
    console.log(parsedCSV[1][2]);
});
}

redraw();

setInterval(function() {
redraw();
}, 1500);
```

[inv.csv]

```
car name,miles/gallon,cylinders,displacement,horsepower,weight,acceleration,model year,origin
"chevrolet chevelle malibu",18,8,307,130,3504,12,70,1
"buick skylark 320",15,8,350,165,3693,11.5,70,1
"plymouth satellite",18,8,318,150,3436,11,70,1
```

Comment: To load CSV files, you should use [`d3.csv`](https://github.com/mbostock/d3/wiki/CSV#wiki-csv), which will take care of the parsing for you.

Comment: [Self Answer] I found problem, when I put <h3> tag in html file and get rid of '.enter().append("h3")' I can see updated value..

Comment: Please consider to close this question or post your solution as an answer to close this question.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I found problem. When I put  tag in html file and get rid of '.enter().append("h3")' I can see updated value..